# How to run cosmos emulator in Azure devops with Ubuntu?

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-cosmosdb

How to run Azure cosmos DB Emulator in Azure devops with spring boot Integration testing (java)?

Currently the cosmos DB emulator only supports Windows server not linux?

Any suggestion how to proceed here?

**Update:1**
For windows build agent, below task can be used which is from azure pipelines.

```
- task: CosmosDbEmulator@2       
    inputs:        
        containerName: 'azure-cosmosdb-emulator'   
        enableAPI: 'SQL'    
        portMapping: '8081:8081, 8901:8901, 8902:8902, 8979:8979, 10250:10250, 10251:10251, 10252:10252, 10253:10253, 10254:10254, 10255:10255, 10256:10256, 10350:10350'       
        hostDirectory: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)\azure-cosmosdb-emulator'
```

For Linux:
I am using the same as of @Ricardo

Comment: Did you try Docker `docker pull microsoft/azure-cosmosdb-emulator`?

Comment: @4EACH The CosmosDB emulator only supports Windows. A Windows container isn't the same as a Linux container.

Comment: ok, As I understood, there is no predefined task by Azure Devops to linux build agent and we need to create our own task for linux based agent?

Comment: @4EACH I am trying with `docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator` as mentioned in the official documentation.

Comment: @sen *How* are you running it? Share your pipeline YAML.

Comment: sorry I cannot share complete pipeline.. but I am using below task    
 `- task: CosmosDbEmulator@2
      inputs:
        containerName: 'azure-cosmosdb-emulator'
        enableAPI: 'SQL'
        portMapping: '8081:8081, 8901:8901, 8902:8902, 8979:8979, 10250:10250, 10251:10251, 10252:10252, 10253:10253, 10254:10254, 10255:10255, 10256:10256, 10350:10350'
        hostDirectory: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)\azure-cosmosdb-emulator'`

as far as I Understood, it needs Windows agent in azure devops, but I am using Ubuntu..

Comment: Getting similar error when running with Ubuntu agent **The container operating system does not match the host operating system.**

Comment: @sen - please move all of your additional info into your question (you can edit your question). This information shouldn't be comments, especially your `task` definition.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Updated my question with more details..

Answer (score 3):

There is an attempt of CosmosDB emulator for linux: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/linux-emulator?tabs=ssl-netstd21#run-on-linux)

They provide commands to run it on a linux machine, we've just put them together in a bash step to be able to run it in our yaml pipelines:

*The sleep is there to give the emulator time to start inside the container

```yaml
- bash: |
        ipaddr="`ifconfig | grep "inet " | grep -Fv 127.0.0.1 | awk '{print $2}' | head -n 1`"
        ifconfig | grep "inet " | grep -Fv 127.0.0.1
        docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator
        docker run -p 8081:8081 -p 10251:10251 -p 10252:10252 -p 10253:10253 -p 10254:10254 -m 4g --cpus=2.0 --name=test-linux-emulator  -e AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_PARTITION_COUNT=10 -e AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_ENABLE_DATA_PERSISTENCE=false -e AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_IP_ADDRESS_OVERRIDE=$ipaddr -d -it mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator
        sleep 30
        curl -k https://localhost:8081/_explorer/emulator.pem > /tmp/emulatorcert.crt
        keytool -cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -importcert -alias emulator_cert -file /tmp/emulatorcert.crt
      displayName: Install CosmosDB Emulator Docker
```

Comment: Yes finally, we are also following the same steps. Are you using Azure pipelines or self hosted agent? Because we are getting Read timeout and service unavailable error intermittently..
@Ricardo

Comment: We are using Azure pipelines and currently facing the same random Read timeouts. We see that the docker image at some point reaches 100% of CPU usage and then fails to process new requests. Even though we are just reading/updating 3-4 documents in total...
We've been able to reproduce it locally and see these in the logs: 
`error code: ReceiveTimeout [0x0010], base error: HRESULT ...
0x80131500,10.202.176.95:10253, payload sent: True, CPU history: (2021-09-16T06:38:37.8611156Z 100.000), (2021-09-16T06:38:37.8611156Z 100.000)
...
, (2021-09-16T06:39:07.8653702Z 100.000), CPU count: 12)`

Comment: Could you please share if you are able to fix this issue? We are sceptical to use this due to intermittent ReadTimeouts and service unavailable errors.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  I get the below output:  Digest: sha256:85c7b1771de120d3...
Status: Downloaded newer image for mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator:latest
mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator:latest
6de23f72f60023ca8af10412c4a31428f7774f7da9c34cc8f21733cf2e47eedd
  % Total    % Receiv..
...--:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8081 after 0 ms: Connection refused
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate
##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.

Comment: (I truncated some output because of char limit)